# Solve for $x$ in $\log(c_1k_1+k_1x^2+2)=2\sqrt{2k_1}y-2\sqrt{2k_1}c_2-2k_1x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While I was solving a differential equation, I got the following form
$$\log(c_1k_1+k_1x^2+2)=2\sqrt{2k_1}y-2\sqrt{2k_1}c_2-2k_1x$$

I want to solve it so as to get $x$ in terms of $y$. Here $c_1,k_1,c_2$ are constants. I thought if I could get a quadratic equation in form of $x$, then I can solve for $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Easy way is get y in term of x.The reverse method does not exist yet.[See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation)

Comment: Actually I want the value of y. I tried to take the logarithm function on L.H.S and the expanding the exponential term by Taylor series. But I am not satisfied with the result. Can anyone help me with some other method. TIA